# Message properties seem to get lost after routing through Azure IoT edgeHub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I am missing something. I also created an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/244) some days before but with no resonance so far.

Here is my scenario:
I'm running a Raspberry Pi as a transparent IoT Edge Gateway with two custom modules in addition to the edgeAgent and edgeHub. The edgeHub is configured to route the messages coming from leaf device to one of the custom module with the route below.

```
FROM /messages/* WHERE NOT IS_DEFINED($connectionModuleId) INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/camera-capture/inputs/input1\")
```

In the module I added a function which listens for incoming messages on input1 and I can see the messages and print the message body. In the leaf device application I'm sending messages via MQTT with application properties (see code snippet 1). When I change the route to...

```
FROM /messages/* WHERE (CameraState = 'true') INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/camera-capture/inputs/input1\")
```

...only half of the messages are routed to the module which indicates that the property is found by the edgeHub and interpreted correctly. However, when I try to extract the properties of the message in the CameraCapture module (see code snippet 2) they seem to be empty (see console output).

So it seems like the message properties are getting lost after routing through the edge hub. Also same result using AMQP.

This is how I send the message (snippet 1):

```
client = IoTHubClient(CONNECTION_STRING, PROTOCOL)
set_certificates(client)
message = IoTHubMessage("test message")

# send a message every two seconds
while True:
     # add custom application properties
     prop_map = message.properties()
     if run_camera:
         prop_map.add_or_update("CameraState", "true")
     else:
         prop_map.add_or_update("CameraState", "false")

     client.send_event_async(message, send_confirmation_callback, None)
     print("Message transmitted to IoT Edge")
     time.sleep(2)
```

This is the receiver (snippet 2):

```
def receive_message_callback(message, hubManager):
    global RECEIVE_CALLBACKS
    message_buffer = message.get_bytearray()
    size = len(message_buffer)
    print ( "Message received: %s" % message_buffer[:size].decode('utf-8'))
    map_properties = message.properties()
    key_value_pair = map_properties.get_internals()
    print ("Key value pair: %s" % key_value_pair)
    return IoTHubMessageDispositionResult.ACCEPTED
```

EDIT: Added Console logs:

```
Message received: test message
Key value pair: {}
Waiting...
Waiting...
Message received: test message
Key value pair: {}
```

Comment: did you miss adding your console output?!

Comment: Added the console output now. The output clearly shows that the message is being received by the module. So routing based on the message properties works. However, when trying to extract the properties within the module, the properties seem to be empty.

Comment: I'm not a python expert so I'm not sure what get_internals() is supposed to be doing. Could you just do `print(len(map_properties))`?

Comment: The map is of the type 'IotHubMap' so unfortunately len() doesn't work. Here is what the docs say: "Map_GetInternals: Retrieves the complete list of keys and values from the map in values and keys. Also writes the size of the list in count."
[link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/map-h/map-getinternals)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is known and tracked on github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/244